# Float layout with reordering in modern CSS

Tags: css, layout

I used to be good at CSS at one point, but the ship has sailed on while I was away.

I need some guidance on how to solve the following case:

1. I have X number of divs where X may change over time
2. The divs "float left" inside a container div, wrapping into rows
3. All the divs have their own rigid width and height
4. The divs have an order that can change and that is important
5. It is desirable that the rows formed by the float layout dont create uneccessary "gaps" (see the marked areas in example below)

So my html is like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div id="item-1" class="item"></div>
    <div id="item-2" class="item"></div>
    <div id="item-3" class="item big"></div>
    <div id="item-4" class="item"></div>
    <div id="item-5" class="item"></div>
    <div id="item-6" class="item"></div>
    <div id="item-7" class="item big"></div>
    <div id="item-8" class="item"></div>
    <div id="item-9" class="item"></div>
    <div id="item-a" class="item"></div>
    <div id="item-b" class="item"></div>
    <div id="item-c" class="item"></div>
    <div id="item-d" class="item"></div>
</div>
```

And my naïve pseudo-CSS is like this:

```
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  float: left;
}

.item.big {
  width: 150px;
  height: 110px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

[image: Illustration of flow]

So my question is, *are there any modern CSS primitives that would solve this case?* Especially, can the order be handeled in pure CSS?

Comment: Don't use float...better use grid or flexbox

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) . Flexbox is a pure CSS solution for that kind of problems. 
All modern browsers supports it, so you can get rid of the `float` in your CSS files.
For better understanding, you can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

Hope it helps.